# Gravity form merge tag {all_fields} not working

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity form and I could not get the {all_fields} merge tag to work. It just displays  {all_fields}. I am trying to show all the filled details in second page in an HTML field. I have tried disabling all the plugins and also changed the theme to twenty seventeen but no luck. Any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge tags are not supported in the HTML field by default. Here is a snippet I wrote that provides support for this.

https://gravitywiz.com/better-pre-submission-confirmation/